# signature of the quadratic form: $f(x,y,z) = xy+yz+xz$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am asked to find the signature of the following quadratic form: $f(x, y, z) = xy+yz+xz$

I have found that matrix wise, $f(x,y,z)= \begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\end{bmatrix}. \begin{bmatrix}0&1/2&1/2\\1/2&0&1/2\\1/2&1/2&0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

How do I find the signature of such a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to compute the eigenvalues.  One helpful insight to that effect is to note that the matrix satisfies
$$
A = \frac 32vv^T - \frac 12 I
$$
where $v = \frac {1}{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)^T$.  Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,-1/2,-1/2$, and the signature is therefore $(1,2)$.